# Which VM solution to use for creating a freeBSD MIPS virtual machine?

Tags: freebsd, mips32

There are a few notable virtualized solutions available to host virtual machines. For example, VMWare Workstation, vSphere ESXi and Virtual Box.

Please suggest which one of these to use for creating a **freeBSD MIPS virtual machine**?
Also, provide any specific h/w requirement for the host running the virtualized solution mentioned above to support MIPS.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to share the answer I got from another channel. May it could help others. Quoting from the link "https://www.reddit.com/r/freebsd/comments/4o8cyc/which_vm_solution_and_hw_to_use_for_creating_a/"

"VMWare and Virtual Box don't run on MIPS or emulate MIPS so that's not even an option.
If you want to run this on x86 and emulate MIPS you can use QEMU or GXemul. There are others but those are probably the most popular/supported. If you had a MIPS machine I'm guessing you wouldn't be asking this question."